# MomentJs only returning dates within the last week in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, time, momentjs

I have a load of dates in a collection in Meteor. At the moment I am just returning them with a limit of 10, but I need to return them up to the last week (7 Days). My problem is there isn't the same number of items in in each day, so I can't just grab the same number for each day. I am using Meteor with moment js. Here is an example of some data and the code I am using to return it:

```js
{
  _id: "a68JFTrCFabQe5qQ2",
  createdAt: Tue Dec 15 2015 09:32:36 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Summer Time),
  user: "7uXThqXFkjkMpDrcb"
}

//This data gets to the client with the following:

getDay: function(day){
  return Time.find({today: day}, {limit: 10}).fetch();
}

//Instead of limiting it by 10 I need items from the last 7 days only.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to search for records with a createAt that is greater than today's date - 7 days. Assuming you are using a normal javascript Date() object when creating these objects in the collection, you would use the following code to get all records within the last week:

```
Time.find({
    createdAt: {
        $gte: new moment().subtract(1, 'week').toDate(),
        $lte: new Date()
    }
});
```

This is if you're using moment. If you aren't, just use regular Date() and subtract a week and put it in the $gt field.